# How should I pass a boost::asio::yield_context in my own functions?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, boost-asio, coroutine

I'm writing a C++11 networking library that uses Boost.Asio under the hood. I want to expose an API that allows users to use stackful coroutines. How should I accept the `boost::asio::yield_context` parameter in my API functions? By value? By reference? By const reference? I have no idea how expensive these `yield_context` objects are to copy.

For example:

```
Result remoteProcedureCall(Args args, boost::asio::yieldcontext yield)
//                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ How to pass?
```

I know that I can take a universal reference and do perfect forwarding:

```
template <typename TYield>
Result remoteProcedureCall(Args args, TYield&& yield)
{
    //...
    boost::asio::async_write(socket_, buffer, std::forward<TYield>(yield));
    //...
}
```

But I would prefer that my API's functions be non-templated, so that I may implement the Pimpl idiom.

Comment: overload it for `const&` and for `&&`, so you can move from temporaries, and at the same time copy objects, and still guarantee that no change will happen to it. Dont know if this will not violate the Pimpl idiom tho(I am not really experienced with Pimpl)

Comment: No, it should not violate Pimpl as long as it doesn't involve template member functions.

Comment: Upon further digging, it would be very unlikely that the `yield` argument would be passed as a temporary. The `basic_yield_context` constructor documentation says: *Most applications do not need to use this constructor. Instead, the spawn() function passes a yield context as an argument to the coroutine function.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It makes a lot of sense that the context has a lifetime that corresponds to that of the coroutine itself.

This means, I anticipate it containing a pointer (or reference_wrapper) to the actual (hidden) implementation state.

That said, simply do as the Boost library itself does, which is to take the `yield_context` object by value.

Comment: I took a look at the `basic_yield_context` header file, and that object contains a `weak_ptr`, two references, and a pointer. Not really that expensive to copy.